# navigation xml has no preview in android studio

Tags: android

I use the code below
It even crashes when I want to open `startDestination`

```
onCreate: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #63: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #63: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

navigation.xml has no preview in android studio

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_nav_wallet"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_userSelectorFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_walletFragment"
        android:name="modularization.features.wallet.view.wallet.WalletFragment"
        android:label="walletFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_wallet" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_transactionListFragment"
        android:name="modularization.features.wallet.view.transactions.TransactionListFragment"
        android:label="transactionListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_transaction_list" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_userSelectorFragment"
        android:name="modularization.features.wallet.view.transfer.UserSelectorFragment"
        android:label="userSelectorFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_selector">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_userSelector_to_transferCreditFragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_transferCreditFragment" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_transferCreditFragment"
        android:name="modularization.features.wallet.view.transfer.TransferCreditFragment"
        android:label="transferCreditFragment">

        <argument
            android:name="username"
            android:defaultValue=""
            app:argType="string" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_transferCredit_to_paymentResultToContactFragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_paymentResultToContactFragment" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_paymentResultToContactFragment"
        android:name="modularization.features.wallet.view.paymentResult.PaymentResultToContactFragment"
        android:label="paymentResultToContactFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_payment_result_to_contact">

        <argument
            android:name="userContact"
            android:defaultValue=""
            app:argType="string" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_paymentResultFragment"
        android:name="modularization.features.wallet.view.paymentResult.PaymentResultFragment"
        android:label="paymentResultFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_payment_result">

        <argument
            android:name="paymentModel"
            app:argType="modularization.libraries.dataSource.models.PaymentModel" />

    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_go_to_userSelectorFragment"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_userSelectorFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_walletFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_go_to_transactionListFragment"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_transactionListFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="false" />

</navigation>
```

Comment: this issue is related to ids, please revise your ids, and I suggest use id as same as fragment name, at last if does not worked, remove all of them and add via android studio visual editor

Comment: @AlirezaTizfahmFard I just updated ids, But it did not worked

Comment: When I change `startDestination` , It works well